# Intermittent Pulses in Anti-phase Step Generator

Tags: transistors, transformer, phase-shift

I've recently been studying some old circuits, in particular some of the Heathkit circuits and I'm currently looking at this one: [IT-1121 Curve Tracer](http://www.vintage-radio.info/download.php?id=224).

Here's a snippet of the step generator which I'm having some trouble with:

[image]

The problem is that the pulses from the collector of Q5 are intermittent, but come and go to a pattern.  You can see the pattern clearly when you adjust the oscilloscope timebase to see the pulses over a longer time.  The sketch below shows the pattern:

[image]

I'm speculating that the signal crossings are somehow being phase adjusted and are gradually moving upwards and away from the 0V reference point.  This explains the gradual fall off to zero in the pulse pattern.  But I'm not sure.

So, my questions are:

**1) What's really happening here and is it "phase jitter" that causing this or something else?**

**2) If it is phase related, how can this occur since the anti-phase signals are generated off a centre tapped secondary (not quite as specified in the Heathkit circuit, but not far off)?**

**3) Is there any way to cure this?**

**UPDATE:** I found the problem.  It turned out to be an issue (bug?) with the DSO.  With a longer timebase, unless the acquisition memory is set > 4k the display ONLY shows the undulating pattern in the pulse signals and not the remaining part of the pulse.  The full pulse is shown if the memory is increased.

Comment: addition: the transistors have some stress! In reverse there is 45V peak via the 10K over the b-e diode. I added an anti-parallel diode (2 times) over them.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty basic circuit: Q5 and Q6 are functioning as a NOR gate for the purposes of producing a pulse on each zero-crossing of the power line. There isn't much that can screw this up, so my guess would be that there's a problem with the ground connection between the PCB and the center tap of the transformer secondary.

Comment: Yep, my thoughts exactly.  It's actually quite difficult to rig a test that enables me to trigger on the crossing point and the absence of a pulse.  The two anti-phase AC signals look fine.  And yet...?